# Oracle Create Stored Procedure to return list

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a task table in which there are 3 columns(id,TimeStamp,Is_procssed).And i have created a stored procedure in oracle as given below.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AUDITING.fetchTasksByTimestamp(
    p_timestamp IN TIMESTAMP,
    p_limit IN NUMBER,
    updated_ids OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
    TYPE NumberTableType IS TABLE OF tasks.id%TYPE;
    l_updated_ids NumberTableType;
BEGIN
    -- Select the IDs of the records to be updated in a thread-safe manner
    SELECT id BULK COLLECT INTO l_updated_ids
    FROM tasks
    WHERE is_processed = 0
    AND timestamp_column <= p_timestamp
    FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
    
    -- Limit the number of records using p_limit
--    IF l_updated_ids.COUNT > p_limit THEN
--        l_updated_ids.DELETE(p_limit + 1, l_updated_ids.COUNT);
--    END IF;
--
--    -- If no records are found, return an empty cursor
--    IF l_updated_ids.COUNT = 0 THEN
--        OPEN updated_ids FOR SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE 1=0; -- Empty result set
--        RETURN;
--    END IF;

    -- Update the tasks that were locked
   
    for indx in l_updated_ids loop
    UPDATE tasks SET is_processed = 1 WHERE id = l_updated_ids(indx);
    END LOOP;

--     Open the updated_ids cursor for the collected IDs
--    OPEN updated_ids FOR
--    SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_updated_ids);

    COMMIT;
END fetchTasksByTimestamp;
```

Above is giving error: "29/17     PLS-00456: item 'L_UPDATED_IDS' is not a cursor" when compiling.

My requirement is to call the stored procedure above from java spring boot in multi thread env.As there are mutiple instances deployed and there is a cron which will call the SP.
I want each thread to get different list of records.Therefore i used skip locked as well.

But the above SP is returning the list of rows which got updated.I tried various way but not able to resolve.

It would be helpful if anyone can help me in resolving issue.

Comment: "is not working"? What is this supposed to mean? You can compile it without errors, but instead of updating rows in the table it plays a song? Or anything else? Please be more precise.

Comment: As to the title: A procedure without out parameters will not return anything. And from the code it doesn't look like you are trying to return anything either.

Comment: Why do you need multithread? I understand you wish to update where timestamp_column <= p_timestamp. For loops with updates in them are really ineffcient. If there are very many rows so that one single update won't do, use dbms_parallel_execute.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I want list of rows(id) which it updated. Also,I tried with return type.But it was giving compile error.Modified the details.Please check

Comment: @BogdanDincescu  So i have n instance of java cron running which will fetch unique rows from task table based on timestamp and limit.And each thread should get unique rows.Therefore i went with above approach in which i will create a SP which each thread will call and they will get unique rows.
Do u have any other approach to work on this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use local PL/SQL collections in SQL (until Oracle 23) and will need to define a collection in the SQL scope.

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER(10,0);
```

You can also simplify the problem using `UPDATE ... RETURNING ... BULK COLLECT INTO ...`.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE AUDITING.fetchTasksByTimestamp(
    p_timestamp IN TIMESTAMP,
    p_limit IN NUMBER,
    updated_ids OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
  l_updated_ids int_list;
BEGIN
  UPDATE tasks
  SET    is_processed = 1
  WHERE  ROWID IN (
           SELECT ROWID
           FROM   tasks
           WHERE  is_processed = 0
           AND    timestamp_column <= p_timestamp
           FETCH FIRST p_limit ROWS ONLY
         )
  RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO l_updated_ids;

  -- Open the updated_ids cursor for the collected IDs
  OPEN updated_ids FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS id
    FROM   TABLE(l_updated_ids);
END fetchTasksByTimestamp;
/
```

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tasks (id, is_processed, timestamp_column) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 0, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' DAY
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_id  tasks.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  fetchTasksByTimestamp(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-08 00:00:00', 5, v_cur);
  COMMIT;
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur INTO v_id;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_id);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> ```

*Note 1: You should not `COMMIT` in procedures as it prevents you from chaining multiple procedures together and if there is an error in a later procedure then `ROLLBACK` them all. Instead, you should `COMMIT` in the code you use to call the procedure.*

*Note 2: Your code does not specify an `ORDER BY` clause when getting the `id`s to update; it is only co-incidence that the first 5 are returned here and without an `ORDER BY` clause the rows could be fetched in any order.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iVjc3oTZ)

---

Or:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE AUDITING.fetchTasksByTimestamp(
    p_timestamp IN TIMESTAMP,
    p_limit IN NUMBER,
    updated_ids OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
  l_updated_ids int_list;
BEGIN
  SELECT id
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_updated_ids
  FROM   tasks
  WHERE  is_processed = 0
  AND    timestamp_column <= p_timestamp
  AND    ROWNUM <= p_limit
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

  FORALL i IN 1 .. l_updated_ids.COUNT
    UPDATE tasks
    SET    is_processed = 1
    WHERE  id = l_updated_ids(i);

  -- Open the updated_ids cursor for the collected IDs
  OPEN updated_ids FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS id
    FROM   TABLE(l_updated_ids);
END fetchTasksByTimestamp;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VAyWlsnl)

Comment: Thanks for providing a way to resolve.But in the above there is no "skip locked" and which will make different threads to have same records.
Can we convert the above to function to return the list while using skip locked?